# Number of combinations w/o repetition that include a certain element from a subset of multiple elements

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I've seen a similar question asked, but only when there was one certain element that needed to be included.

My question has to do with considering a set $S=\{1,2...,20\}$, calculate how many subsets of size 4 can be constructed which contain at least one of the elements from the set $M=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

My initial thought was that if we consider that the element from set $M$ can be arbitrarily placed in the first position, we have 5 options for choosing the first element, and then what's left can be represented by $19\choose 3$, but this $\bigg(5\cdot {19\choose 3}\bigg)$ is equivalent to $20\choose 4$, which can't be right.

I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can best solve it by using the complement, thus

{all subsets of $4$} - {subsets of $4$ with none of the "special five")

$ = \binom{20}4 - \binom{15}4 = 3480$

---

**ADDED**

The other way which you were trying (though rather painful) will also work with correct figures, so you should know how to do it that way, too.

$\binom51\binom{15}3 + \binom52\binom{15}2 + \binom53\binom{15}1 + \binom54\binom{15}0 = 3480$

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out the error in your thought process: Since there can be more than one element of $M$ in your subset of size $4$, you will count such subsets multiple times, each time with another element of $M$ put into the first position.

For example, the one subset $\{1,2,19,20\}$ will be counted twice with your method, once as $1$ being in first position and $\{2,19,20\}$ for "choose any $3$ from the remaining $19$ elements", and a second time with $2$ being in first position and $\{1,19,20\}$ chosen from the remaining $19$. That's why your method overcounts.

$\{1,2,3,4\}$ would be counted $4$ times by your method, for an extreme example.